# How to display data in the form list in list using Adonisjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, multidimensional-array, database-relations, adonis.js

I have a data that only one list, i want to display this data like list in the list,

this is my query and how i returned it:

```
const cart = await DB
    .select('carts.id_cart','carts.id_product','product.shop_id','product.product_name','product.price',
                'shop.shop_name','shop.address', DB.raw('count(carts.id_product) as quantity'))
    .from('carts')
    .leftJoin('product', 'carts.id_product', 'product.product_id')
    .leftJoin('shop', 'shop.id_shop', 'product.shop_id')
    .groupBy('carts.id_product')
    .where({'product.is_deleted':'0'})

return response.json({
    status:true,
    message: false,
    data: cart
})
```

And result of this code like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "id_cart": "1",
            "id_product": "1",
            "shop_id": "1",
            "product_name": "test1",
            "price": 11111,
            "shop_name": "John Doe",
            "address": "Quis et eu cumque Na",
            "quantity": 1
        }
     ]
```

I want the result changed like this:

```
[

    "status": true,
    "message": false,
    "data": [
        {
          "id_cart": "1",
          "shop_id" : "1",
          "product" : [
             {
                "id_product": "1",
                "product_name": "test1",
                "price": 11111,
                "shop_name": "John Doe",
                "address": "Quis et eu cumque Na",
                "quantity": 1
             }
          ]
        }
    ]

]
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The support for same has been added.[to do a nested query builder in AdonisJs](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-lucid/issues/92)

`.whereHas` and `.has` is help to you and see this link: [Inject new data into query object](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/inject-new-data-into-query-object/489)

in query we use `jsonb_agg` and `jsonb_build_object` when to make nested object.